# jQuery Scroll: detect end and start

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

EDIT >> Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/LY7LUAylvKQ3pIv9lhYM?p=preview

I've implemented jQuery Scroll for Tab-Titles, it works well.

[image]

If I am at the beginning the arrow on the left side should disappear and when I move right it should be shown. If I am at the end the arrow on the right side should disappear.

How could I detect the start and end points ? I want to be able to react on window-resizing.

These are the buttons:

```
 $('#nextTabBtn').click(function () {
     var $target = $('.tabBoxMantle');
     if ($target.is(':animated')) return;
     $target.animate({
         scrollLeft: $target.scrollLeft() + 300
     }, 800);
 });


 $('#prevTabBtn').click(function () {
     var $target = $('.tabBoxMantle');
     if ($target.is(':animated')) return;
     $target.animate({
         scrollLeft: $target.scrollLeft() - 300
     }, 800);
 });
```

Comment: Try adding the markup as well or a fiddle will be great.

Comment: put ur code in jsfiddle, you can find scrollLeft position using scroll event, so set as disappear using css based upon scroll position

Comment: @Mayank Question updated, plunker added.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Angular so here's *most* of an answer. [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/TkRUKgabWXh6egXMSUnV?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you @Shikkediel, it is also a practicable solution.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the reply. Maybe you could still cherry pick something from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not too familiar with Angular but still i have given a try to fix your issue

I have created function to toggle Prev Tab and Next Tab Button as follows

```
function ShowPreviousTabBtn() { // handles prev tab button visibility
  var $targetScroll = $('.auTabBoxMantle');
  if ($targetScroll.scrollLeft() == 0)
    $('#prevTabBtn').hide();
  else
    $('#prevTabBtn').show();
}
function ShowNextTabBtn() { // handles next tab button visibility
  var $targetScroll = $('.auTabBoxMantle');
  var $scrollwidthtotal = $targetScroll[0].scrollWidth;
  var $scrolledwidth = $targetScroll.width() + $targetScroll.scrollLeft();
  if ($scrollwidthtotal <= $scrolledwidth)
    $('#nextTabBtn').hide();
  else
    $('#nextTabBtn').show();
}
```

Complete working code of your app.js is given below

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller(

  "MainController",
  function($scope, $http, $window, $document, $location, $anchorScroll) {

    $scope.my = {};
    $scope.my.title = "jQuery Scroll Example";


    $http.get('data.json')
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.my.tabs = data;
      });

    function ShowPreviousTabBtn() {
      var $targetScroll = $('.auTabBoxMantle');
      if ($targetScroll.scrollLeft() == 0)
        $('#prevTabBtn').hide();
      else
        $('#prevTabBtn').show();
    }

    function ShowNextTabBtn() {
      var $targetScroll = $('.auTabBoxMantle');
      var $scrollwidthtotal = $targetScroll[0].scrollWidth;
      var $scrolledwidth = $targetScroll.width() + $targetScroll.scrollLeft();
      if ($scrollwidthtotal == $scrolledwidth)
        $('#nextTabBtn').hide();
      else
        $('#nextTabBtn').show();
    }

    // Initially hide the previous Tab button
    ShowPreviousTabBtn();
    // Hiding the Next Tab if the Items div is not overflown
    ShowNextTabBtn();

    $('#nextTabBtn').click(function() {

      var $target = $('.auTabBoxMantle');
      if ($target.is(':animated')) return;
      $target.animate({
        scrollLeft: $target.scrollLeft() + 300
      }, 800)
      .promise().done(function() { // used as a callback function for animate
        ShowPreviousTabBtn();
        ShowNextTabBtn();
      });

    });

    $('#prevTabBtn').click(function() {
      var $target = $('.auTabBoxMantle');
      if ($target.is(':animated')) return;
      $target.animate({
          scrollLeft: $target.scrollLeft() - 300
        }, 800)
      .promise().done(function() { // used as a callback function for animate
          ShowPreviousTabBtn();
          ShowNextTabBtn();
        });
    });

  }


);
```

I hope this works for you :)

Comment: thank you very much, would you put it on the plunker, it does not work in my environment.  I've to react on window-resize, this code from angular can capsulate it: `angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {

        });`

Comment: Prev is working next not, I've changed it to `($scrollwidthtotal <= $scrolledwidth)`, now it is working. Would you please update your answer, so that I can mark it as correct? Thank you!

Comment: OK it works fully, thank you! Before anyone cries, now I have to bring everything into the form, as Angular would expect normally. DOM manipulation in Angular must clearly happen in directives. :)